# Typo3 v7.6 and Imagemagick not work

Tags: image, imagemagick, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

[image]

[image]

I have installed typo3 7.6. To work with the images set, I installed Imagemagick 7. Then I added the necessary paths in the configuration. I tested it, but it does not work.
What is the reason?

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe you must surround the paths with double quotes as they contain spaces... `"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick...\"`

Comment: By fault V7 Imagemagick uses magick not convert. If you install legacy programs convert should also work. Where do you specify your Imagemagick command? identify would also need changing to either magick identify or magick -identify.

Comment: Quotes have nothing to do with it. As for the obsolete versions, the version of typo3 is not the oldest, it uses imagemagick from version 6 and higher. Also previously installed imagemagick 6 did not work.

Comment: Try searchin the web sometimes: "Since the current ImageMagick Version 7 uses a general magick.exe and not single apps like combine.exe, convert.exe, composite.exe and identify.exe anymore, IM is not detected by TYPO3's configuration module any longer and subsequently fails the setup tests.
As a temporary workaround you have to provide those 4 still expected apps as symlinks to magick.exe.
It would be good if now TYPO3 could try to detect and use IM also the "new way".
This was tested on a Windows Server."

Comment: But all the files listed by you are in the root folder as well as magick.exe. What is the point of creating symlinks if these files are needed by typo3.